# Display ratings with numbers - ratyrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rate

I can seem to figure out how to use the ratyrate gem to display the ratings in numbers instead of just with stars. here is my code

```
Valuable | <%= @course.rates("valuable").count %> ratings : 
  <%= rating_for @course, "valuable", enable_half: true %> 

Fun | <%= @course.rates("fun").count %> ratings : 
  <%= rating_for @course, "fun", enable_half: true %>

Easiness | <%= @course.rates("easiness").count %> ratings  : 
  <%= rating_for @course, "easiness", enable_half: true %>
```

The documentation gives this as a solution, but it does not work for me

```
<%= rating_for @movie, "original_score", target: "#hintDiv", targetFormat: "Score: {score}" %>
```

Comment: atleast          <% = rating_for @user, "performance", imdb_avg: true, disable_after_rate: true %>        like this code shows me imdb style rating with average score(may be this could help to you), but i wasn't able to view multiple stars